# Checking a TextBox for an empty string, an integer or a string

Tags: c#, winforms

I am checking a text box for the following

- If there is no input
- If the input is between 0 and 100
- If the input is a string other than a number

The code -

```
if (this.BugCompPct.Text == String.Empty)      
else if (Convert.ToInt32(this.BugCompPct.Text) > 100 | Convert.ToInt32(this.BugCompPct.Text) < 0)
//Not sure about checking the last if
```

What could I put as the if conditional to check for a string other than an integer?
I want only the input to be an integer and nothing else

Thanks

Comment: Also store the value this.BugCompPct.Text before checking it twice. Now it has to parse it twice.

Comment: I guess you should use a [masked textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What could I put as the if conditional to check for a string other
>   than an integer?

Use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method to see if the parsing is succesfull.

For empty string use [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) (supported on .Net framework 4.0 and later), For .Net framework 3.5 or lower you can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` with `string.Trim`

Your check will all the conditions could be like:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BugCompPct.Text))
{
    int temp; 
    if(int.TryParse(BugCompPct.Text,out temp)
    {
        if(temp >= 0 && temp <= 100)
        {
            //valid number (int)
        }
        else
        {
            //invalid number (int)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Entered text is not a number (int)
    }
}
else
{
    //string is empty
}
```

Comment: actually your `is not a number` should be `is not a Integer`, because it could be an double or do i miss something?

Comment: @WiiMaxx, thanks for pointing that out, its just a comment, but I modified it for clarity :)

Answer (score 1):

every value put into a textbox is as string. I would then advise you to tryparse rather than convert.to.
*(Why? tryparse can be handled much easier and won't crash and burn if there are bad values put into it)*

just use int.TryParse(txtbox1.text, out i)

You must define integer i above this

then you can use if statements using i (the integer version) to validate it.

To check if its an integer only just use:

```
if(!int.TryParse(txtbox1.text, out i))
{
    // do work
}
```

then you can use > < in if statements to check how big the number is.

Answer (score 1):

First check if `TextBox` is empty, then if string is valid number and last check boundaries.

```
int number = 0;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.BugCompPct.Text)
{
    //not valid
}
else if (Int32.TryParse(this.BugCompPct.Text, out number))
{
    if (number > 0 && number < 100)
    {
       //valid
    }
}
```

Comment: I used an aspect every answer in my final solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows form you should use masked textbox.